# For Android Wi-Fi, is it possible to monitor in / out (e.g. up / down) data transfer information?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I want to re-present the data transfer arrows for Wi-Fi (as seen in the Quick Settings panel) in my app. I have been looking at the source code for Quick Settings and have been roadblocked by a couple of non-public APIs (AsyncChannel & WiFiManager.getWifiServiceMessenger) - does anyone know if there is any conceivable way around this?

For example, NetworkController...

```
    // wifi
    mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Handler handler = new WifiHandler();
    mWifiChannel = new AsyncChannel(); //Private
    Messenger wifiMessenger = mWifiManager.getWifiServiceMessenger(); // Private
    if (wifiMessenger != null) {
        mWifiChannel.connect(mContext, handler, wifiMessenger);
    }
```

...is handled in...

```
// ===== Wifi ===================================================================
class WifiHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            ...
            case WifiManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_NOTIFICATION:
                if (msg.arg1 != mWifiActivity) {
                    mWifiActivity = msg.arg1;
                    refreshViews();
                }
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

...where `mWifiConnectivity` is communicated to the Quick Setting panel.

I am thinking this is not possible, but thanks for your consideration and confirmation of this hunch :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051445/android-app-successfully-monitors-wifi-data-use-successfully-disconnects-wifi) here in SO, looks like he's done the monitoring part.

Comment: Ahh - this is an interesting work around. I'll come back and mark this as Answered if nobody provides a more direct method. Thanks!

Comment: It worked! Not as clean as w/ telephony but not too bad of a performance hit either. Thanks for highlighting this workaround!